# Collapsible Window with WPF

Tags: .net, wpf

How can I make a window in WPF that looks like the attached (notice the "collapse" button to the left of the minimize/maximize buttons)? I've sifted through the documentation at length to no avail. Any insight into this matter is much appreciated :)

[alt text http://www.study.en0de.com/cwindow.jpg](http://www.study.en0de.com/cwindow.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing really specific to WPF for doing this. You have to resort to Win32 P/Invoke to draw in the non-client area. Fortunately, searching for topics related to this is very easy if you search for `WM_NCPAINT` ( [google](http://www.google.com/search?q=WM_NCPAINT) / [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=WM_NCPAINT) ) but unfortunately, it's not trivial to do. So I don't think it would be very helpful for my to write up a complete example when there's many C# examples available here.

The only thing specific to WPF that you need to do is use the `HwndSource` class to specify a hook procedure to process the message.

```
protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnSourceInitialized(e);
    var source = (HwndSource)PresentationSource.FromVisual(this);
    source.AddHook(WndProc); // a function to process windows messages
}
```